# Python environment

Tags: python, environment

When working with multiple Python environments, is it possible to activate the desired environment before working on a specific project. How to select correct Python interpreter and dependencies are used for that project?  Activation can be done by using commands?

Comment: which tool you are using to manage your Python environments.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Use https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 1):

Here are the activation commands for `virtualenv` ,`conda` , `pipenv` :

1. `virtualenv`:Virtualenv is a tool for creating isolated Python environments. To activate a virtualenv environment, you need to run the activation script specific to your operating system.

On Windows:

```
path\to\env\Scripts\activate
```

On Unix or Linux:

```
source path/to/env/bin/activate
```

2. `conda` :Conda is a cross-platform package and environment manager provided by Anaconda. To activate a conda environment, you need to use the following command:

```
conda activate environment_name
```

3. `pipenv` : Pipenv is a tool that combines pip package management and virtualenv functionality. To activate a pipenv environment, you can use the following command:

```
pipenv shell
```